# Asynchronous persistence in Python

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, dask

I need to speed up the execution of a Python script that reads a large CSV file in chunks, does some processing and then saves the processed rows into a database. It takes comparable time (1.5sec) to process 10,000 rows then to persist them. The times do have some fluctuations, of course, sometimes processing is faster, sometimes persisting.

Unfortunately, processing the records cannot be easily parallelized because the processing is historical (the records are stock trades and there are calculations based on previous activity). It's possible but for this question, something that can be done is to parallelize processing a chunk with persisting the results of the previous chunk. This should halve the total time.

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
    # the following two tasks in parallel
    persist (rows_from_previous_chunk) # this is I/O waiting, mostly
    rows_to_save = process(chunk)      # this is Python, not C
    # wait for the above to finish
    rows_from_previous_chunk = rows_to_save
```

My question is about which are the recommended ways to do the above. I can think of a few:

1. Given that one task is mainly I/O waiting, there's a chance I can use multithreading without running into GIL contention.
2. A second option is to use Dask, specifically [Delayed](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed.html). However, given the short time used by each task (under 2s), I'm not sure it's the best approach.
3. A third option is to have one process read & process the rows then send them over a bounded queue to a separate one that will do the saving to the db. It's overkill to use a JMS queue, I'm thinking of `multiprocessing.Queue()`

Any advice is appreciated. I'm a long-time Java programmer who recently made the switch to Python and learning to live with the GIL, hence the question.

Comment: This looks like a map/reduce kind of operation. There are tools available that may be handy, like spark. It may be worth to take a look.

Comment: I'm familiar with Spark but data is not that large to justify it (~50-100GB) and I cannot fully parallelize processing because processing each row depends on the predecessors. Some smarter partitioning can be done but it's for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following approach. Interestingly, using multithreading didn't work as expected; passing the dataframe to another queue for saving was still blocking the main thread from continuing the work. Not 100% sure what's happening, but in the interest of time I switched to using processes and it works. The code is a tad simplified for clarity below, in reality I used multiple db worker processes.

```
import multiprocessing

# this function will run into a separate process, saving the df asynchronously
def save(queue):
    db_engine = create_engine(...)
    while True:
        df  = queue.get()
        if df is None:
            break
        df.to_sql(schema="...", name="...", con=db_engine, if_exists="append", chunksize=1000, index=False)
        queue.task_done()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    queue = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue(maxsize=2) 
    worker = multiprocessing.Process(name="db_worker", target=save, args=(queue,))
    worker.daemon = True
    workers.start()

    # inside the main loop to process the df
        queue.put(df_to_save)

    # at the end 
    worker.join()  # wait for the last save job to finish before terminating the main process
```

Answer (score 1):

Dask does add overhead, but very small compared to your typical 2s task time. To maintain ordering, you could have each task depend on the previous one. Here is a stab at it

```
@dask.delayed
def process_save(rows_from_previous_chunk, chunk):
    if rows_from_previous_chunk:
        persist(rows_from_previous_chunk)
    return process(chunk)

parts = dd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize).to_delayed()

prev = None
for chunk in parts:
    prev = process_save(prev, chunk)
out = dask.delayed(persist)(prev)
dask.compute(out)

out.visualize()  # should look interesting
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try next week.

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on your database but if one exists the simplest way may be to use an asynchronous library like [aiomysql](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiomysql) or [asyncpg](https://github.com/magicstack/asyncpg)to allow you to execute the insertion queries in the background.

The I/O bound portion can execute without requiring the GIL lock so your Python portion of the code will be able to continue.

Comment: Interesting. Sadly, the db is MS SQL Server.